# Simple hover effect issue

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create simple hover effect on a div with the following codes.

http://jsfiddle.net/9kVXS/

I can't get it to show the alert box. What am I doing it wrong? Thanks for the help.

Comment: it works fine after selectiong JQuery on the left side

Comment: @neu-rah - did'nt see your comment, but post it as an answer as you where the first to post it. Preferably the FlyingCat should just delete the entire question !

Comment: no problem, i would had an answer if i wished so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to select jQuery in the dropdown menu on the left : http://jsfiddle.net/9kVXS/2/

Answer (score 1):

You weren't including jQuery in your JSFiddle. Choose any version of jQuery and it will work.

Screenshot: http://www.evernote.com/shard/s1/sh/b2fb419c-6c73-45c3-9a38-52a3ab5c23b3/1b2ef5293842ccb366d43c21ef02324d